# WPF data binding - good FULL explanation of data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

There are a lot of intros to DataBinding out there.  But they leave out a lot of the databinding options.

Does anyone know a good reference / instructional document that goes through most/all of the wpf databinding options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN's [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) page really covers just about every aspect of WPF's data binding.  Granted, you'll have to follow links for more details, but every topic is at least mentioned (with links to more specifics) on that single page.

It includes specifics about the mechanics, basic concepts, conversions, validation, templating, and debugging.

Comment: Would also suggest Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed (SAMS) and Silverlight 4 Data and Services Cookbook (PACKT Publishing) The last one even though for Silverlight covers a lot of data binding techniques